# Procedures needed to be followed to run Mathematica remotely on a presently physically inaccessible machine

Tags: remote-access, run

I have a computer (iMAC), on which I log in and run Mathematica, located on campus. However, due to present circumstances--familiar to all of us--I do not have physical access to it. (I do have a home laptop with Mathematica installed on it.)

What are the steps needed to follow to run Mathematica from my home on the campus machine? I assume this is doable in some manner.

Comment: What access do you have to the remote computer from home? If you can log into it, you could just do that and run your computation, right? Or do you mean that you want to run the front end on your local computer, connected to a kernel on the remote one?

Comment: Thanks! Well, obviously I should email the campus computer manager and ask him how I can remotely log in. I just thought I wanted to run jobs on the campus machine--and have some limited output available to me at home via the cloud. (I once had it set up to send me such output--when I was away--but don't now recall the specifics of how that was done.) I hadn't thought of   running  "the front end on your local computer, connected to a kernel on the remote one", as you suggest as a possibility. Do you--mainly out of curiosity--have a reference on how that could be done?

Comment: Why not try to ask your campus computer manager to try to install TeamViewer on your iMAC? :https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mac-os/

Comment: Wow! I wasn't aware of TeamViewer. Could you briefly indicate how it might be used in relation to my goals?